# SELECT records from a GROUP BY where string in field is 'I1' and there are no records in the GROUP BY with string 'H4'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, where-clause

I have a data table that looks as below.  I need to select records GROUPED by ref field where MessageType field is 'I1' but no records in the GROUP are MessageType 'H4'.  I'm not a pro on SQL so I'm sure my code is laughable but bare with me.  Also the Ref may have /001 on the end some times so I need to use SUBSTRING in the Select and GROUP BY.  So in the below table I need only REF2_ABCD to be selected as it has MessageType I1 but not another record that is MessageType H4

[Table]

| Ref | MessageType |
| --- | --- |
| REF1_ABCD | I1 |
| REF1_ABCD/001 | H4 |
| REF2_ABCD | I1 |

[/table]

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Ref,1,9) AS LRN,
MessageType
FROM table1 dh
WHERE MessageType IN ('I1', 'H4')
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Ref,1,9),MessageType
HAVING MessageType = 'I1' AND NOT MessageType = 'H4'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Having` can be used to filter on aggregated results. In this case, I think, you do not need it.

```sql
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Ref,1,9) AS LRN,
MessageType
FROM table1 dh
WHERE MessageType IN ('I1')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table1 t 
                  WHERE t.MessageType = 'H4' 
                   and SUBSTRING(t.Ref,1,9) = SUBSTRING(dh.Ref,1,9))
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Ref,1,9),MessageType
```

Note: `MessageType IN ('I1')` can, if needed/wanted, be written as `MessageType = 'I1'`

Comment: Many thanks.  I thought a sub query might be in order however this is not yet working.  I am getting the following error "Cannot find either column "t" or the user-defined function or aggregate "t.SUBSTRING", or the name is ambiguous."  I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2010 FYI

Comment: oops, the enter is in the wrong place I do see a line starting with `HERE`, and the previous line ending with a `W`.  That should have been one word `WHERE`  (I will edit my answer)

Comment: I also added the tag [tag:sql-server] to your question. Which should be there is you need an answer which is specific to SQL-SERVER  (see description of [tag:sql])

Comment: Thank you Luuk but I did notice the line break so I did have the correct Syntax but still get the same error.

Comment: I think I have resolved this by declaring the table in the SUBSTRING e.g. SUBSTRING(t.Ref,1,9) -@Luuk do you want to edit your answer and I can mark as the Answer?

Comment: Indeed, I should test those thing before I type them....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Ref,1,9) AS LRN
FROM table1 dh
WHERE MessageType not IN ('H4')
GROUP LRN
```

or if you need 2 fields in output:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Ref,1,9) AS LRN, messagetype
FROM table1 dh
WHERE MessageType not IN ('H4')
GROUP LRN, messagetype
```

Comment: that is first not valid sql and second the result must be only REF2_ABCD and not both